# How can I get item's workflow details/workflow history where workflow association has been deleted?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-history

We have lots of list items where workflow instance is not showing on workflow details page. After researching i found that in sharepoint 2013, completed/suspended/terminated workflow instances will be automatically removed by auto clean up timer job and workflow manager after 30 days.

Due to this we can't able to get log history/error details of that items. So my question is, Can we get item's workflow details/history where workflow association has been deleted?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the workflow history list by the link below. The workflow history list is the hidden list and store the workflow details in SharePoint 2013.

http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History

There is a column named “List ID”, then you could filter the list by list id to get the details of the workflows associated to the list.

To avoid the issue, you could consider disabling “Workflow Auto Cleanup” timer job in central administration.

Comment: I know WF History list. But we cant able to get history logs of specific list item in one view. In my case there are almost 150 entries logged per item. So it will be difficult.

Comment: To display the 150 entries in one view, you could modify the view and scroll down, in the bottom of the page, in the item limit,  you can enter the number of items to display in one view. And you can enter 150 and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Workflow History list in SharePoint Online there is no way to associate a task in this list with the item in the list where the workflow originally ran. Both the List ID, and Primary Item ID columns are empty.

I have a requirement to get the workflow history of all items in a list. Most have since had their workflow history removed from the item, so I was hoping to find the original history for each item using this list, but it is not possible!!!